# How to get the total value for distinct columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get the total value for distinct coloumns ?

```
 ------------------------------------------------------
| order_no    |    company  | destination  |  total   |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|----------|
|     100     | Burger King | Los Angeles  | 100      |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|----------|
|     100     | Burger King | Phoenix      | 100      |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|----------|
|     101     | Burger      | Los Angeles  | 101      |
------------------------------------------------------
```

I mean the total value for order_no 100 is 200 . Like that. How can I get this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use sum and group by as below:

```
SELECT ORDER_NO , SUM(TOTAL)
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY ORDER_NO;
```

You will get output as:

```
ORDER_NO    TOTAL
-----------------
100         200
101         101
```